# Is it safe to delete "My First Project.rcproject" file in the "iMovie Projects" folder?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, imovie

I am totally new to "iMovie" so I would like to ask you if it's safe to delete "My First Project.rcproject" file in the "iMovie Projects" folder (as it appeared from nowhere, maybe it was result of opening "iMovie")?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you are safe to delete it, just as long as you didn't add anything important to it.

Answer (score 3):

That is the default name of your first project. If you haven't done any work with it, you should be able to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to project library and you will see the first video you created
2. click it and go at the top screen
3. click on file and then "move to trash"

That's basically it